# Countdown Timer which shows on the UI with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, countdown

I'm trying to implement a Countdown Timer which shows on the UI,
I thought this was a clean and elegant solution but Logcat throws

```
AndroidRuntime(3282): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

,

```
private class UpdateCountdownTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Long, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Long... millisUntilFinished) {

        new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished[0], 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                publishProgress(millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer)).setText(answer);
            }
        };
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... millisUntilFinished) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(millisUntilFinished);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText(""
                + millisUntilFinished[0] / 1000);
    }
}
```

Still don't fully understand threads. Can anyone tell me what  I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Very Sorry. I am an absolut incompetent. I had forgotten to call the metod start() on the counter. :P 
 I finally went for implementing the countdown with the CountDownTimer by itself. Sill don't know if this actually runs on a separate thread or not but it works now.

```
    CountDownTimer myCounter = new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText(""
                    + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            System.out.println("I am ticking");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    };

    myCounter.start();
```

Comment: Only main UI thread may update UI like TextView, thus you cannot update view from another thread.  You should wrapp your textView.setText("123") inside something like this mTextView.post(new Runnable(){}) either runOnUIThread() http://stackoverflow.com/q/12850143/2163045

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is the onFinish() method inside CountDownTimer. Here you're modifiying the UI thread, and you cannot do this from a background thread. So you have to put `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer)).setText(answer);` inside onPostExecute() method. I mean:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer)).setText(answer);
}
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this would do it, but I've tried and still throws the exact same Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to connect the UI when doing somthing in background.In my opinion what you want is possible if you use a thread.This will make your work much more easier.A small piece of code is shown below.I hope this may help you.I am trying to set an image instead you can settext.Here i had done using a thread and a handler.Its impossible to connect the UI inside the thread.In assynctask When you are doing something in background you are compleatly inside the thread.Thats why you are getting a error here.Otherwinse you can do it in `Postexecute()`

```
Thread animator = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                while (i < 4) {
                    sleep(50);
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(i));
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
    animator.start();
    handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub1);
            } else if (msg.what == 1) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub2);
            } else if (msg.what == 2) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub3);
            } else if (msg.what == 3) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub4);
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: I was using AsyncTask as an Android recommendation. I think is more clear. Still, even if I move the onFinish() piece of code as I told @isidoro-castell-egea I still get the error. The fact I modify a View from the onProgressUpdate() shouldn't be a problem since that's suppossed to be called from UI, isn't it?

Comment: Can you make it lil more clear??This error usually occurs when one tries to update the UI from inside thread or if its an assync then from background.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using Handler to update UI every second?

checkout http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Thx @Veer, I'd seen this a couple of days ago. I decided to go for AsyncTasks following Android guidelines. Also I think is more clear. I'll go for this one if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Link is broken. You should provide the relevant code.