# android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3147)

Tags: android

Any idea why would this crash appear? The trace has only native code so very hard to track it down. Happens on Samsung Galaxy s3 platform 4.1.2 when I run animation inside a `Fragment` and when animation ends I call `notifyDataSetChanged` for the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. The issue is not 100% reproducible.

Thanks.

Trace:

```
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3147)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1144)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2273)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2145)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1956)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-01 11:50:11.836: E/AndroidRuntime(21136):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: hello, please provide log

Comment: Somehow there is connection that when I run animation in the Fragment, there are 2 Fragment's in the pager. And after animation I modify the list and when notifyDataSetChanged is called, there will be only one Fragment.

Comment: seems you have `null`, please use debugger and check step by step when it occurs

Comment: But the trace has no point of my own written code, so me having null means that platform has null and I can't debug that.

Comment: so it means you should put breakpoints in few places and then you will know if the problem happens after `this` breakpoint or `that` breakpoint :)

Comment: I located the problem and got possible fix for this weird crash. Little more testing and if works I answer myself for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fix was simple but no idea why works.

In the `AnimationListener`'s `onAnimationEnd` callback I had a callback which triggered `notifyDataSetChanged`. I add that callback into `Runnable` and ran the `Runnable` with `getView().post`

```
@Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    getView().post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // notifyDataSetChanged here
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answer but as in all things Android these answers become dated pretty quickly.
I would use runOnUiThread now. I was running in a baseclass with the animator as a private class. For a deeper dive on runOnUiThread see
[Android basics: running code in the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread)

```
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        //
        MyBaseActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");                    
            }
        });

    }
```