# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. No runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I have done quit a bit of my first android game already and it works good. Now I need to make the screen refresh like every second so my counter in game refreshes.

Doing a timer gives this problem:

Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I've searched stackoverflow and the solution is to create a runnable. I don't know how that works. I create one and then the program breaks because context doesn't work in runnable

```
error: constructor DrawGame in class DrawGame cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What can I do? Why would I need a runnable. My game is a simple chess type game.

Tried to do it like this:

```
public class DrawGame extends View implements OnTouchListener {


Timer turnTimer = new Timer("timeLeft", false);
TimerTask countDown = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

       invalidate();

    }
};




public DrawGame(Context context){
    super(context);

    Turns.turnTimeCounter();
    Turns.yourTurn();
    turnTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(countDown, 1000, 1000 );

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
//lot of code
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample code that throws the exception?

Comment: [android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread)

Comment: `program breaks because context doesn't work in runnable etc` do you think that's all someone will need to know top figure out what your problem is?

Comment: post the code end full LogCat error

Comment: You might want to use a [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html). There's no sense in refreshing the whole screen (which means redrawing everything) just to refresh a timer

Comment: Updated part of code how I tried to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only edit the state of a `View` when you are in the main thread. When you are in a timer you are from a separate thread. Use this to post the action to the main thread.

```
counter.post(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        counter.setText(newTime);
    }    

});
```

Comment: Sorry, what is counter? My IDE doesn't understand the command. Is that some object you have created?

Comment: It is a reference to your view.