# Android Studio displaying a single element to webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

In Android studio is there such thing as retrieving only a single element from a website and sending it to a webview?

Lets take https://accounts.google.com/ as an example. If I want to only display the "Create account" button, how can I delete all the elements except that create button with class "RveJvd snByac" and without having to manually do this: "document.getElementByClass('AnyOtherClass').style.display='none'; "?

Or is there a javascript command that can delete all elements but bring back this element with class name "RveJvd snByac"?

Here is what I have tried:

Element with id=yDmH0d is the html body. Element with class name=RveJvd snByac is the element I want to keep.

```
webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        webView1.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementById('yDmH0d')[0].style.display='none'; })()"+
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('RveJvd snByac')[0].style.display='block'; })()");

    }
});
webView1.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/");
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `getElementsById`. And you have syntax errors.

Comment: My bad. It should be document.getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use JSoup to load your  elements selectively into webview.

Refer this,
[Load document to WebView with JSOUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074071/load-document-to-webview-with-jsoup)