# Android invalidate() not updating textView

Tags: android, refresh, textview, invalidation

I'm trying to make a textView update alongside a timed loop. I've tried making it invalidate() every time it loops. This seems to work, but the app crashes when the timer starts.

Here's the loop:

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        thangO += 10;
        textypoo.setText(Integer.toString(thangO));
        textypoo.invalidate();
    }
};

public void start() {
    if (timer != null) {
        return;
    }
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 2000);
}
```

Here is the onCreate where I initialize some stuff:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    textypoo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textmcview);

}
```

Here are 2 onClick method. One that updates the textView whenever I press it, and another that calls the timer:

```
 public void sendthestuff(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    textypoo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmcview);
    thangO++;
    message = Integer.toString(thangO);
    textypoo.setText(message);


}

public void bazinga(View view) {
    start();
}
```

Comment: try with run on ui thread

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry, I'm new to the Android side of Java.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out by putting the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread into the timer. Thanks for the help ( :

Comment: just go and do bit google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        thangO += 10;
        textypoo.setText(Integer.toString(thangO));
        textypoo.invalidate();
    }
};
```

To:

```
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                thangO += 10;
                textypoo.setText(Integer.toString(thangO));
                textypoo.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
};
```