# Refresh view after TextView.setText

Tags: android, textview, refresh

I have a TextView that is updated but I cannot see the refresh until i minimize and reopen the application. here is the code that performs that.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bleAdapter = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bleAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

        device.connectGatt(this, true, new BluetoothGattCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
                TextView state;

                switch (newState) {

                    case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED: 
                        state = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.state);
                        state.setText("Connected = True");
                        state.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;

                    case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                        state = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.state);
                        state.setText("Connected = False");
                        state.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I need to refresh that TextView? I'm doing anything else wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `onConnectionStateChange` is being fired? Put a breakpoint somewhere within that method and see if it hits?

Comment: Yes, it hits. Because if I minimize and reopen the application that textView get updated.

Comment: I mean while the app is running.

Comment: Yes, I've tested it right now and It hits while app is running.

Comment: Put a toast at your cases (connected or not). Maybe you will realize it's not a TV matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should update the **TextView** in the main **(ui) thread**, like this

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            state.setText("Connected = False");
            state.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

or if you project is [configured to support java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development) you can write it more concisely

```
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
       state.setText("Connected = False");
       state.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    });
```

Comment: Do I have to do this whenever I need to update the view?

Comment: Yes, all views must be updated on the UI thread since android's UI framework is single threaded. If you find this approach too verbose you can try others like the ones mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread. You could also use a reactive (RxJava/RxAndroid) or publish/subscribe approach and specify the thread to process the received event through an annotation. I am pretty fond of https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for its ease of use.