# background thread how to update UI periodically

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, rx-java

How to run background thread correctly or run timer to update UI every 1 second? I mean when a activity is paused thread should be paused, when activity resumed thread or timer should be resumed and every second data must be updated on UI.

Comment: Those are possible ways to run code in UI Thread:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread)

Comment: Any update? Could you mark as solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HandlerThread class to create the thread, like below:

```java
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandler");
handlerThread.start();
Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
```

After that, launch your runnable this way:

```java
  handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            // runnable code here

            // call again thread after 1000 millis
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }, 1000);
```

HandlerThread class, as every class in java, inherits from `Object` class that has `wait()` method. If you check the documentation, it says "Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object."
You should pause the thread by calling `handlerThread.wait()` according to your activity lifecyle, for example inside `onPause()` method. Remember to call `notify()` on the same thread instance when your activity is resumed, typically inside `onResume()` method.
Call `handler.removeCallbacks` when you're done :)