# Change Color everysecond AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Hello again guys firstly i am new at android studio.i am trying to make countdowntimer and i made it its working

then i want to make change background color every tick , every second.

thank you!

```
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), " %02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
            textView.setText(text);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            textView.setText("done.");
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 153, 51));

        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: What would be the colors for each tick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that on each tick you are setting the background color to white and then immediately to red, inside `onTick`. This will most likely result for the user to not be able to see the white color, because it is immediately overwritten on every tick. You need a way to change to a single color for each tick.

Don't forget to always run UI related code on the UI thread. You can read more about on how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread).

In case you want to alternate between white color and red for every tick, then you can have a flag in your `CountDownTimer` like so:

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    private boolean white = true;

    @Override
    public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int color;
                if (white) //Select color depending on flag's value:
                    color = Color.WHITE;
                else
                    color = Color.RED;
                white = !white; //Flip the flag.
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(color);
                String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), " %02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
                textView.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setTextSize(20);
                textView.setText("done.");
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 153, 51));
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

Or better, you can rely on the value `millisUntilFinished` which is given as the single argument to `onTick`, like so:

```
final long total = 10000, interval = 1000;
new CountDownTimer(total, interval) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final long millisElapsed = total - millisUntilFinished;
                final int color;
                if ((millisElapsed / interval) % 2 == 0)
                    color = Color.WHITE;
                else
                    color = Color.RED;
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(color);
                String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), " %02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
                textView.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setTextSize(20);
                textView.setText("done.");
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 153, 51));
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

This approach should be better because if I understand correctly from [the documentation of `CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer#java), it seems that the `millisUntilFinished` (given in `onTick`) is not guaranteed to be a multiple of the interval, which would depend also on the amount of work the `onTick` method is doing.