# Change property of Button from another thread within the same class in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to change the value of an element from a different thread

The error is on function `gameButton.setText(String.valueOf(out));`, I am aware I am not allowed to change main UI elements from external threads.

What is the least complicated way to change the value of this element from an external thread?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DFT sProc = new DFT();
    Button gameButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout gameLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        gameButton = new Button(this);

        //Add the start Button
        gameButton.setText("Start");
        gameButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        gameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        gameLayout.addView(gameButton, buttonDetails);
        setContentView(gameLayout);

        final Thread t = new Thread(this::soundThread);
        t.start();
    }

    private void soundThread(){
        for(ini i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sProc.start(this);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                double out = sProc.getAmplitude();
                gameButton.setText(String.valueOf(out));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            sProc.stop();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread)

Comment: You can't modify the `gameButton` from the background thread you should modify it in the main thread, try `runOnUIThread` method